# Как во Vue из массива имён выбрать случайное?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Подскажите пожалуйста.  Есть список из 10 тысяч элементов, в каждом элементе в HTML есть тег

Name

.

В data Есть массив Names: ['Богдан','Руслан' ...]. Как сделать что бы выбиралось случайное имя из массива Names и вставлялось в тег `<p>Names</p>`

`<p>{{Names[Math.floor(Math.random() * Names.length)]}}</p>`  -- вот так почему-то не работает

```
    <f7-list
  media-list
  virtual-list
  :virtual-list-params="{ items, renderExternal, height: $theme.ios ? 63 : ($theme.md ? 73 : 46)}"
>
  <ul>
    <f7-list-item
      v-for="(item, index) in vlData.items"
      :key="index"
      media-item
      link="#"
      :title="item.title"
      :subtitle="item.subtitle"
      :style="`top: ${vlData.topPosition}px`"
    >
    <f7-block strong>
      <p>Name:{{Names[Math.floor(Math.random() * Names.length)]}}</p>
    </f7-block>
    <f7-block>
      <p>Surname:</p>
    </f7-block>
    </f7-list-item>
  </ul>
</f7-list>

        <script>
export default {
    data() {
 Names: [ "Bogdan", "Vladimir", "Nikolay", "Stepan", "Sergey", "Igor", "Vladislav", "Miroslav", "Nikita", "Alexander", "Ivan", "Ruslan", "Maria", "Victoria", "Angella", "Zhanna", "Irina", "Marina", "Yulya", "Olya", "Dasha", "Natasha", "Masha"]
  const items = []
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1) {
    items.push({
      title: `UserID ${i}`,
      // subtitle: `SurName ${i}`,
    });
  }
  return {
    items,
    vlData: {
      items: [],
    },
  };
},
methods: {
  renderExternal(vl, vlData) {
    this.vlData = vlData;
  },
  randomName(){

  },
  loadMore(event, done) {
      window.location.reload();
  }
},
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никогда! Слышите? Никогда не выносите такие конструкции в шаблон. Потом сами себе  спасибо скажете. Для подобных вещей есть `computed`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      names: [ "Bogdan", "Vladimir", "Nikolay", "Stepan", "Sergey", "Igor", "Vladislav", "Miroslav", "Nikita", "Alexander", "Ivan", "Ruslan", "Maria", "Victoria", "Angella", "Zhanna", "Irina", "Marina", "Yulya", "Olya", "Dasha", "Natasha", "Masha"]
    };
  },
  computed: {
   randomName() {
     return this.names[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.names.length)];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{randomName}}
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, я только второй день как начал учить vue )